# my sqrt function will not compile in GHCi

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I want to get the squareroot of an `Int`, the Prelude `sqrt` function is for `Float ⟶ Float` and I need `Int ⟶ Float`.

Attempting to roll my own simple sqrt I defined the two types and copied the function from the Prelude source code on Hackage:     `sqrt x              =  x ** 0.5`

so:

```
sqrt' :: Int -> Float
sqrt' x = x ** 0.5
```

gives error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: x ** 0.5
      In an equation for ‘sqrt'’: sqrt' x = x ** 0.5
   |
19 | sqrt' x = x ** 0.5 
   |           ^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried different type class definitions, using an intermediary variable and the where clause  and so on but no joy.

*EDIT ⟶*

p 285 Excerpt from [The Haskell Book](https://haskellbook.com) which is a prettier version of the Haskell documentation illustration [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#standard-classes).

[image: types in Haskell]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-) can only be applied to [**`Floating`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating) types, and furthermore requires that both operands and the result all have the same type.

Your type signature on the other hand, says that `x` is an `Int` (an `Int` is *not* a member of the `Floating` typeclass), and furthermore `x ** 0.5` should return a `Float`, so this violates the type signature of `(**)`.

We can convert any type that is a member of the [**`Integral`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) to any type that is a member of the [**`Num`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) . In this case `fromIntegral` will thus convert an `Int` to a `Float`:

```
sqrt' :: Int -> Float
sqrt' x = fromIntegral x ** 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks,  I was trying `int2Float` and `round` for back the other way, which I found with Hoogle but couldn't get it to load (reading docs about how to `import` now). I didn't realise the (**) function needed a Float import, of course it does!

Answer (score 1):

```
isqrt :: Int -> Float   -- but realy, 
-- (Integral a, Floating b) =>         a    ->    b
isqrt n = sqrt $ fromIntegral n
```

would just work in the first place.

How it works is `sqrt :: Float -> Float` (or `Double -> Double`, but really

```
sqrt         :: Floating         b =>       b ->  b
```

) needs its argument to be of the right type, and

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

does the job.

Any `Integral` type is already a `Num` and so is any `Floating` type:

```
> :i Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where    -- subclass of Real
  ......
  toInteger :: a -> Integer

> :i Real
class (Num a, Ord a) => Real a where      -- subclass of Num
  ......

> :i Num
class Num a where
  ......
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a

> :i Floating
class Fractional a => Floating a where    -- subclass of Fractional
  ......

> :i Fractional
class Num a => Fractional a where         -- subclass of Num
  ......
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a good cheat sheet on numerical types in Haskell. I found a cheatsheet on package but it gives scant attention to numerical typing, it's not very helpful at all. For instance, what's the diff b/w Floating and Float, one is type class and the other is a type? is that all. lots of other uncertainties for me.

Comment: don't know if there is any. :) using `> :i Float` etc. can help. or [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Floating). Just need in general pay attention to types, `> :t sqrt` etc.

Comment: I made a simple insert function for putting an Int into an ordered list in its correct place based on order. Works for literals i.e.
`insert 3 [1,2,4,5]`  -- returns [1,2,3,4,5] But if I define a list: `a = [1,2,3,5]`;
`inset 4 a` -- produces a type mismatch error, `[Int]` expected not [Integer]. 
Changing the function definition from `[Int]` to `[Integer]` fixes it, as does defining a as Int. i.e.
a = [1,2,3,5] :: [Int]

Whats the difference b/w Int and Integer , I searched Hoogle and package but couldn't locate anything and `:I Integer` refers me to definitions in GHC.Classes etc

Comment: I found this which kind helps: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-Integer.html#t:Integer 
Why would `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` assume `[Integer]` type rather than the simpler/smaller `[Int]` type?

Comment: yes `Int` and `Integer` are two different types. you can control the exact type by giving an explicit, specific type signature: `a :: [Int] ; a = [1,2,4,5]` or `a = [1,2,4,5] :: [Int]` or `a = [1,2,4 :: Int, 5]`. regarding the choice, it is called "type defaulting rules in GHCi". it can be googled. cheers, :)

Comment: I added a cheat sheet on some fo the number typeclasses (it shows Ints are an element of several type classes like Num, Real, Bounded, Intergral)  which I found in The Haskell Book by Christopher Allen & Julie Moronuki ... this was the kind of thing I was looking for I guess.